# TypeError: task.dueDate.toDate is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am using Firebase as my Database and nextjs. I want to read data from firebase. when I try to read due date which is a timestamp datatype I face this error. here is how I read data from firebase code:

```
const dbInstance = collection(firestore, "tasks");
useEffect(() => {
  getTasks();
}, []);

const getTasks = () => {
  getDocs(dbInstance).then((data) => {
    setTasksArray(
      data.docs.map((item) => {
        return { ...item.data() };
      })
    );
  });
};
```

in return statement when I tried to map through all tasks, everything went well except the due date.so i googled the solution and saw toDate() function. I used `task.duedate.toDate()`  and there raised the error

The best I could do is this:

```
{tasksArray.map((task) => {
  return (
    <Flex
      flexDir={"column"}
      key={task.creatorId}
      hidden={task.priority != "" ? true : false}
    >
      <Text>{task.taskName}</Text>
      <Text fontSize="xs">
        {safeJsonStringify(task.dueDate)}
      </Text>
    </Flex>
  );
})}
```

it returned this: {"seconds":1683300279,"nanoseconds":338000000}

But i intent to display it like in a moderate way like here in stackoverflow

Comment: Can you run `console.log(typeof task.dueDate)` right before the `return` statement?

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions

Based on the latest output, I assume that `dueDate` field is a JS Object, rather than an instance of Firebase Timestamp, with a format similar to:

```
{
  seconds: 1683300279, 
  nanoseconds:338000000
}
```

Then, if it's an Object, there's no built-in method `.toDate`.
Given the assumptions above, here are two solutions:

### 1. Creating a Firebase Timestamp out of the Object

```js
const timestamp = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(dueDate.seconds, dueDate.nanoseconds)
```

That would instantiate an actual Timestamp that has access to the `.toDate` method.

### 2. Converting JS object to Date using time arithmetics

JavaScript accepts milliseconds on the `new Date()` constructor.

Then, you can convert your object data to milliseconds and then build a JS Date from it, by doing:

```js
const NS_TO_MS_MULTIPLIER = 1/1000000
const SEC_TO_MS_MULTIPLIER = 1000

const timestampInMilliseconds = dueDate.seconds * SEC_TO_MS_MULTIPLIER + dueDate.nanoseconds * NS_TO_MS_MULTIPLIER

// Date takes the amount in milliseconds and build a Date object
const date = new Date(timestampInMilliseconds)
```

I've examplified both methods on a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-khayyam-68iw0p?file=/src/App.js